# Erro de "Dados Inválidos" ao tentar descriptografar um arquivo utilizando TripleDES

Tags: c#, criptografia

Estou desenvolvendo uma rotina que descriptografa informações de um documento ".txt" utilizando TripleDES.

Porém ao descriptografar ele gera o seguinte erro:

> Dados inválidos.

No StackTrace está assim:

> em
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32
>   hr)    em
>   System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._DecryptData(SafeKeyHandle hKey,
>   Byte[] data, Int32 ib, Int32 cb, Byte[]& outputBuffer, Int32
>   outputOffset, PaddingMode PaddingMode, Boolean fDone)    em
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoAPITransform.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[]
>   inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)    em
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count)    em
>   CriptografiaPortabilidadeTeste.CriptografarXML_3DES.DecryptTextFromMemory(Byte[]
>   Data, Byte[] Key, Byte[] IV) na d:\Projetos\Sistemas Internos
>   Cecresp\CriptografiaPortabilidadeTeste\CriptografiaPortabilidadeTeste\CriptografarXML_3DES.cs:linha
>   180

Segue código para melhor compreensão, evento:

```
    private void btnDescriptografar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            TripleDES tripleDESalg = TripleDES.Create();

            // Nome do arquivo completo.
            string FileName = txtbArquivo.Text;

            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(FileName))
            {
                string path = @"c:\testeDescriptografado3DES.txt";

                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
                {
                    string s = "";
                    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        byte[] linhaBytes = new byte[s.Split('-').Count()];
                        int i = 0;
                        foreach (var item in s.Split('-'))
                        {
                            linhaBytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(item);
                            i++;
                        }

                        //Criptografia da string para dentro da memória buffer
                        string resultado = DecryptTextFromMemory(linhaBytes, tripleDESalg.Key, tripleDESalg.IV);

                        //Escrita para um novo arquivo.
                        sw.WriteLine(resultado);
                    }
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Arquivo descriptografado");
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
    }
```

Método "DecryptTextFromMemory()":

```
    public string DecryptTextFromMemory(byte[] Data, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        try
        {
            MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(Data);

            TripleDES tripleDESalg = TripleDES.Create();

            CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt,tripleDESalg.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV),CryptoStreamMode.Read);

            byte[] fromEncrypt = new byte[Data.Length];

            //AQUI DISPARA-SE O ERRO!!!
            csDecrypt.Read(fromEncrypt, 0, fromEncrypt.Length);

            return new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(fromEncrypt);
        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A Cryptographic error occurred: {0}", e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Qual é o motivo desse erro?

Comment: Não entendi essa linha aqui: `csDecrypt.Read(fromEncrypt, 0, fromEncrypt.Length);`. `fromEncrypt` neste ponto está vazio em teoria. Não era pra ler de `Data`?

Comment: Poderia mandar as linhas do arquivo em questão?

Comment: Cigano, no caso o "csDecrypt" possue o "msDecrypt", que possue o enfim o "Data". Entendeu?

Comment: @Reiksiel, o arquivo que estou usando é de teste. Tem 3 linhas com três nomes aleatórios. Nada de demais

Comment: @MatheusBessa, achei esse link https://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/cryptographicexception-bad-data-209425.aspx. Poderia verificar, acredito que pode ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

O erro ocorreu nessa linha: `linhaBytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(item);`

Prova:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segundo a [documentação](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y57wwkzk.aspx) a string deve conter `apenas números`.

O que acha de converter sua string para um `Byte[]` dessa forma:

```
byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(yourString);
```

Fonte: [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360839/conversion-to-byte-gives-this-error-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format)

Comment: Não, não... O erro não é disparado ai. E quando o eu entro no método, u consigo enxergar o array de bytes preenchidos de forma correta. Estou pesquisando a classe "CryptoStream" acho que o erro está lá.

Comment: @MatheusBessa, desculpe o meu erro ocorreu na linha informada. Poderia me passar as linhas do arquivo que você usou para simular?

Comment: Desculpe @Reiksiel, algo ficou mau informado, rs. O meu arquivo criptografado tem o seguinte formato: "233-12-100-24-52". Então o split, separa em array e depois atribui ao array para cada item. Eu tinha entendido errado a sua primeira pergunta. Desculpe, falha minha.

Comment: Teste com essa sequencia de bytes num txt: "9-182-191-15-62-72-246-246-52-75-202-159-101-239-66-98-41-244-99-101-189-140-47-91-20-113-22-99-74-118-251-174".

Comment: @MatheusBessa, da erro ao ler ao preencher a posição 22 do array no valor 47, irei tentar sem ele ok?